# Elemental Potassium as both an oxidizer and a reducer

Tags: redox

On this table I realized that elemental potassium could adopt oxidation states of -1, 0, and +1.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oxidation_states_of_the_elements

Does this mean that elemental potassium can function as both an oxidizer and a reducer? I understand that oxidizers are reduced (gain electrons), and that reducers are oxidized (lose electrons). How can potassium anion be formed? The potassium anion must be extremely unstable due to potassium's extremely low electronegativity, correct?

Also in what compound does potassium actually have a negative oxidation state?

Comment: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v317/n6034/abs/317242a0.html  This abstract seems to suggest the ion is made in a solution of liquid crown ether.  I'm assuming the affinity of the crown ether for K+ is so strong that a potassium atom can take an electron from another potassium atom.

Comment: Which table are you referring to? @brinnb This might be a similar approach like solvated electrons from sodium or potassium $\ce{Na/K (s) + (n + m) NH3 (l) ->[][-78~^\circ\mathrm{C}] [Na(NH3)_{n}]+/[K(NH3)_{n}]+ + [e- . (NH3)_{m}]}$.

Comment: Martin, thank you, and I have included the link to the table on the OP.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C19128962&Mask=8)

Comment: Did you realize that the K anion existed a priori?

Comment: yes I knew it, but it was just because my book had question which of the following can act as both oxidizing and reducing agent and answer was K:)

Comment: Which book is that? I must take a look.

Comment: It's Modern fully solved MCQ's semester 1 class 11. Publisher Kautulia. These book helps to prepare for JEE(joint entrance exam)

Comment: Is this for the JEE?

Comment: Also in general how does one realize that the K anion exists, a priori?

Comment: @Dissenter Ya this book help to prepare for JEE but just for class 11 when you don't know to much stuff. I don't think anyone can realize about it unless he/she have read it in  some books or using stack exchange ;)

Comment: AFAIK, sodium in presence of 0.5 equivalent of proper crown ester disproportionate into complex of positive ion and crown ester and negative ion, and the solid salt was obtained, but I can't find the reference, sorry. Likely same for potassium. Surprising enough, negative potassium ion is more stable, that double oxygen anion. AFAIK, all or most double negative anions are unstable to dissociation into monoanion and free electron. Still, we have compounds with oxygen in -2 oxidation state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compounds having potassium anions are referred to as [potassides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalide) and are rare, usually involving K- within a cyrpt such as:

[image]

[Crystalline Salts of Na- and K- (Alkalides) that Are Stable at Room Temperature](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja992667v) J. Am. Chem. Soc. vol. 121, pages 10666-10667 describes preparation of K+(aza222)K- , where "aza222" is the compound in the above figure, but with the 6 H's replaced with methyl groups.  The compound is formed by dissolving potassium metal in methyl amine solution of the methylated aza222.